# Load testing API to trigger different transactions based on set percentage

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for Load testing my API endpoint.
My API accepts JSON payload with few key value pairs. I have configured my payload to have a couple of key-value pairs to be passed from csv data file.
While running my load tests... I want to trigger 80% of transactions with 1 key value pair while remaining 20% transactions to trigger with 2nd key value pair.
Example:
Imagine my payload have a field named "Product" which accepts values "VEGAN" and "NON-VEGETARIAN".
I want to hit 80% of transactions with "product" value as "VEGAN" and 20% of transactions to hit with value as "NON-VEGETARIAN"

Is there a provision in Jmeter to set this % of transactions or any hack to simulate such load.

I did try to have different product values in the csv data sheet but could not set a specific % of transaction as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set 80% of "NON-VEGETARIAN" payloads and 20% of "VEGAN" payloads in the CSV file the final distribution will match your requirements.
2. Another option is using 2 [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for these 2 options with number of threads and/or iterations
3. If you prefer to stay with a single Thread Group you can consider using [Throughput Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) where you can specify the desired number of executions in absolute or percentage values
4. There is also [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter) which is more convenient and easy to use

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. 
I tried with Weighted Switch Controller with JMeter v5. Works smoothly. However I have my org supporting JMeter v4 only. So could not get it running on cloud.
I have tried Throughput Controllers and that worked seamlessly.